# Should I download the Hardware drivers that Windows Provides or drivers from Manufacturer's website?

Tags: drivers, windows-8.1, graphics-card, amd-radeon, dell-inspiron

today I've installed Windows 8.1 and everything is working as it should be
but I'm stuck at installing the Graphic drivers, I have a **Dell Inspiron 5537** with **AMD Radeon HD 8670M**, I've found a driver on Dell Support for my laptop graphic driver, but on AMD website I've found an Up-to-date driver for my Radeon HD 8670M, also Windows Update provides a driver..
So the question is

> Should I download the driver from Dell website, or
>   AMD Website, or Windows Update?

Comment: If the machine will let you, use the drivers from AMD. Some laptops won't allow generic drivers - in that case you have to use the ones from the laptop manufacturer instead [til they stop being bothered to make them, then you're stuck] :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a graphics card, the most up to date driver will be the AMD one.
You can safely use it.

Also, the driver's architecture (32-bit or 64-bit) has to match your operating system's architecture.